# Extjs Not Showing data from store

Tags: javascript, extjs, model, store

I`m learning Extjs and trying to follow this tutorial http://www.sencha.com/learn/the-mvc-application-architecture/ 
Everything went well..
But when I continue to 'Creating a Model and a Store' and do as written in tutorial then run it.
It give error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined
Is there is something I missed up?
Thank you

/app/controller/User.js

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores: [
        'Users'],
    models: ['User'],
    views: [
        'user.List',
        'user.Edit'],
    init: function () {
        this.control({
            'viewport > panel': {
                render: this.onPanelRendered
            },
            'userlist': {
                itemdblclick: this.editUser
            }
        });
    },

    editUser: function (grid, record) {
        var view = Ext.widget('useredit');

        view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
    },
    onPanelRendered: function () {
        console.log('panel rendered');
    }
})
```

/app/model/User.js

```
Ext.define('AM.model.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['name', 'email']
});
```

/app/store/Users.js

```
Ext.define('AM.store.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'AM.model.User',

    data: [
        {name: 'Ed',    email: 'ed@sencha.com'},
        {name: 'Tommy', email: 'tommy@sencha.com'}
    ]
});
```

/app/view/user/Edit.js

```
Ext.define('AM.view.user.Edit', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias : 'widget.useredit',

    title : 'Edit User',
    layout: 'fit',
    autoShow: true,

    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = [
            {
                xtype: 'form',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name : 'name',
                        fieldLabel: 'Name'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name : 'email',
                        fieldLabel: 'Email'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];

        this.buttons = [
            {
                text: 'Save',
                action: 'save'
            },
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                scope: this,
                handler: this.close
            }
        ];

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

/app/view/user/List.js

```
Ext.define('AM.view.user.List',{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.userlist',
    store: 'Users',
    title: 'All users',

});
```

/myapp.js

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'AM',

    controllers : ['Users'],
    appFolder: 'app',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'userlist',
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="myapp.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Loading apps.........
    </body>
</html>
```

Extjs library is located at
/extjs

Comment: why not point to examples/app/simple on your extjs extracted directory, this do the same thing as you want to achieve but have one issue. I got the solution for this issue as an answer bellow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as a syntax based comment, you have an extra comma after 'userlist' in your myapp.js file and also after 'All Users' in your List.js file.

Also, in the comments on that tutorial there is reference to a similar issue where the resolution was to:

> define the ‘columns’ property for the ‘List’ view

Try adding this to your list:

```
columns: [
    {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name'},
    {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email'}
]
```

Comment: Ran into the same issue and adding columns did the trick for me too. I had ExtJS 4.0.7, I am wondering if this is fixed in 4.1

Answer (score 0):

Okay look like that you want to try the sencha mvc example @ examples/app/simple
This example have a bug because the need to explicit load of `Ext.container.Viewport` on application launch

```
launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', { //this line do explicit load on Viewport class
```

So to solve this you need an extra line on your `myapp.js` at the first line

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true}); //need to enable dynamically load the Ext.container.Viewport
Ext.application({
    name: 'AM',

    //paths direct to the Ext src path folder i.e given here if accessed from http://localhost/ext/examples/app/simple/simple.html
    paths: {
        'Ext': '../../../src/' 
    },
    controllers: [
        'Users'
    ],
....
```

Comment: console give me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined. But above previous answer solved it.